# Javascript error in IE7 only (jQuery / Cycle.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, cycle

I'm using jQuery and cycle.js to fade through some images on this site.

On the first and last slides, I've put a callback function to go to the next/prev pages, however in IE7 I'm receiving a runtime javascript error (not in any other browsers).

Here's the link to my javascript file: http://bit.ly/dAKEof

The error I'm receiving in IE7 is:

Line: 126
Char: 4
Error: Object Expected
Code: 0

Here's the code I have at line 126 of the functions.js file:

window.location = $('#next').find("a").attr("href");

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a javascript debugger for IE(like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268445) please use it to find out what is happening. If you have microsoft office 2003/visual studio the debugger comes with it, but during installation you have to select the component to install. It will allow you to see what is happening when this line is getting executed. For further references you can use the following links 1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see a link to the site with the error in your question but saw a url in your profile and went there to see if that might be the one. Looks like it is...

IE is notorious for giving incorrect line numbers in its javascript errors. The error is actually on line 125:

```
function onBefore(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
    // If the page isn't loading or refreshing - initCycle == false (fixes auto unbinding of slide opts on load)
    // If is last slide and next slide is fwd direction go to next project instead of wrapping cycle
    if(opts.currSlide + 1 == opts.slideCount && fwd && !initCycle){
        opts.end(opts); // <-- this line is failing b/c the end function is null
        window.location = $('#next').find("a").attr("href");
    }
    // If is first slide, and next slide is bkwd direction go to prev project instead of wrapping cycle
    else if(opts.currSlide + 1 == 1 && !fwd){
        opts.end(opts); // <-- this also fails for the same reason
        window.location = $('#prev').find("a").attr("href");
    }
}
```

The `end` function in the `ops` object is null, and that's where the error is. Interestingly, I checked in FF as well and this is also true there, but it seems to recover more gracefully than IE in this case.

It's not entirely clear from the rest of the code how the `onBefore` function gets called. Looks like it might be the cycle plugin itself. In any event, wherever that call happens the `opts` object appears to not be getting populated with all the data that is needed by your function.

**Update:**

I took a look at the cycle plugin code and `opts.end` is a callback that the user of the plugin must supply. So the solution to your problem is to either provide your own callback when you create the cycle object (line 101 in your js file) or remove the lines in your code that invoke the `end` function.

**Update in response to OP's comment below:**

Upon closer inspection your code will actually do exactly what you want without the need to invoke an `end` callback, so you can safely remove those lines. The plugin triggers your `onBefore` callback before it does any animations. And since you reload a new url in the browser when moving backward from the 1st slide or forward from the last one, it never even gets to the fade animation, which is your goal.

However, to answer your question on how to add an `end` callback to the original cycle object, you would do it exactly as you did for `onBefore` and `onAfter`. Create a function with whatever code you want to execute and then include `end: yourFuncName` in the object hash passed to the plugin. Another way to stop the cycle plugin is `$(selector).cycle('stop');`. But again, none of this is needed in your case. Just remove the calls to `end` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Bryan! I see exactly where your talking about, sorry I'm very beginner level with JavaScript in general. You've helped tremendously!

Currently the end function onBefore is making sure that the image doesn't fade if it is the first or last slide on the page, although the call for this function is incorrect.

How can I go about adding this as a callback function on the original cycle object? Or is there a better way to stop the fade on the onBefore callback function for the cycle?

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: I've spent some more time looking at this today. The problem is that when I remove the opts.end(opts); from the callback, even though the window.location function is onBefore and therefore should be triggered before the fade, it doesn't. The fade will initiate in any case, and then the location will change shortly after. 

The strange thing is that when I put opts.end(opts); in, this doesn't happen.

Comment: Interesting. In that case try replacing those lines with `$('#slider').cycle('stop');`. If that works you can then, if you want, put that new line in its own function and pass it in when creating the cycle plugin as described in my last update. You would then need to put back the `opts.end(opts);` which would trigger the new callback.

Comment: Hey Bryan,

The problem was that normally the `onBefore` callback should trigger before the animation fade, however because I had "if statements" contained in the `onBefore` callback some of the animation was fading before the link was called.

I found that if I set the cycle to `nowrap`, this will fix the problem of the preemptive fades on the first and last slides. But then I needed a way of binding the click event to the prev/next buttons, and rebind the cycle if the user changes direction on a slide. 

New code here: http://bit.ly/dAKEof

Worked it out with your help and direction, thanks!